# How to link an active directory to a webpage?

Tags: php, mysql, security, active-directory

I have an interview in a few days think this could be a possible question because of my previous work experience. What would be the steps to link a pre-existing active directory to a web application which has a php/mysql backend and html/js/css frontend?

Comment: Do you mean active directory the micro$oft program?

Comment: Do you mean just having authentication running from an active directory? PHP [does LDAP](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ldap.php) though you might have fun re-writing all the code to use the data in there instead of using it's own user tables. Sounds simple enough, just change the authentication, but when you start looking at all the possible SQL queries that hit those tables and start thinking about how they have to suddenly all be changed, it gets a lot nastier.

Comment: So what would be the best way to add authentication security to a web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access Active Directory data using LDAP protocol. PHP offers LDAP functions which allow you to connect Active Directory and make some queries: [PHP LDAP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ldap.php).

If you want to find out more, there are many available resources, for example a book: [Integrating PHP with Windows](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145303059.do).